# Texture tiling between adjacent edges in 3ds max

Tags: animation, game-engine, 3dsmax

Please take the look at images that are attached , 
I want to design a simple game level , So I have created a plane geometry for the floor . by duplicating this plane and welding the instances , I can create a long corridor.
Then I had downloaded a texture which is seamless and tile able , and it is 256x256 pixels which atlased in a 1024 x 1024 pixel texture at Left Top Corner , it means at coordinates of 
`{(0,1),(0,0.75),(0.25,0.25),(0.25,0.75)}` .

So I had assigned a material with texture mentioned above to plane object and then with Unwrap UVW modifier , I had set the UVs of the plane exactly ! exactly to match the 256x256 portion of the atlas texture. Please note that Atlas texture background is black .

So when I weld the two duplicates of the floor , problem which is shown in the images below will occur :

Image 1 :

[image]

Image 2 :

[image]

If you cannot see the images, I will tell you the problem. the problem is that , a black line which it has the color of the atlas texture background appears between two adjacent edges of the planes and makes them non-seamless.
So how can I blend the edges seam to not show the texture background ?

I don't want to scale down the faces a bit in UVW Modifier dialog , I want to keep it exactly at the coordinates that I had mentioned above.

Comment: What file format is your texture? Does it have a alpha channel?

Comment: it is psd file texture without alpha channel

Comment: Could you upload a samplefile with this tiling and include the texture? And what version of max are you using?

Comment: I had understand this will cause when sampling occurs and this is for texture filtering , some one has solved this with Premultiplied alpha , what's that ?

Comment: You find premultiplied alpha checkbox in the 'bitmap' texture settings, (it's enabled as default).

Comment: @Stig Atle Steffensen  , please check this post : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049577/angrybots-environment-floors ,is this texture ,a  premultiplied one ?

Comment: Try the suggestion in this thread:
http://forums.cgsociety.org/showthread.php?t=496772

"Actually, under the layers menu in photoshop, at the bottom in the matting options, you have the ability to "remove black matte" (or white matte). This basically will un-premultiply your image for you so that you can use it in photoshop without getting that black outline around the edges of your renders....."