# Angrybots Environment Floors

Tags: opengl, unity-game-engine, directx, game-engine

Have your ever payed attention to the environment floor's texture of the angry bots demo which comes with unity3D ? here is the texture :  (why this atlas texture looks like this with less alpha ? )

[image]

This Texture  name is **EnvironmentFloorTiles_A** and I Wonder how they have created this and why they had to this ? I had opened this in a new standard material in 3DS max and applied this to a plane with UV's modified , by a miracle it was mapped on the plane as a chromatic texture. Perhaps there is a relation to the alpha channel. but I don't why and what?

Comment: [Texture atlas](https://www.google.com/search?name=f&hl=en&q=texture+atlas)

Comment: @Drop are you kidding me ? I know this is a atlas , but why it has less alpha  ?

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had found the answer ! if we erase or make a png transparent , we don't remove the RGB channel , but we are removing the alpha channel of that which is embedded on it ! So if we erase and transparent a png , we make that transparent pixel color black in it's alpha channel , very long thread I had started contains the full answer :

[Link to the answer thread in unity3d forums](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/231563-Premultiplied-Alpha-PNG-Or-Something-new)